# Create and configure a Laravel project with PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpstorm

I am quite buzzed with the whole Homestead stuff and how it correlates with an IDE. Let's say I have my PhpStorm installed in `~/Developer/PhpStorm` The Homestead is in `~/Developer/Homestead`. This is how my YAML file in Homestead looks like:

```
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Developer/Homestead/workspace
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: helloworld.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

So, you see that I have a workspace folder in the Homestead directory.
I also have another directory: `~/Developer/workspace/PHP` where I am planning to store my projects, instead of in the Homestead folder.

I installed the Laravel plugin in PhpStorm. And, in order for the Laravel plugin to work in PhpStorm, [this generated file](https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822) is needed. My questions are:

1. Where exactly should I put the `_ide_helper.php` file so that PhpStorm works properly with Laravel? Should I paste it in each project or just once somewhere?
2. Do I have to write a different app name in the YAML **sites: map** field for every project that I want to be launching atm?
3. How do I create a new Laravel type project. As when I go for creating a new project in PhpStorm, there are types of which I can choose - should I also have Laravel listed there, because I do not? Because now, when I create a new PHP project - it's completely empty. And I suppose a Laravel project should have some architecture and generated files.
4. I beg of a simple explanation of all this Laravel + Homestead stuff and Vagrant and how to control my projects, because I am getting very frustrated and I have to start working with these technologies on my Bachelor project soon.

Comment: I can recommend you to use Laravel plugin for PhpStorm instead of helper: much easier and it's creator constantly improving the plugin. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532?pr=phpStorm

Comment: @Kootli - that is what I have installed already. But still the helper is needed. It is even mentioned in the plugin's installation guide. :)

Comment: About your first question: Just copy the helper file to your project root and synchronize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You shouldn't need to put the `_ide_helper.php` file anywhere manually, it is automatically generated by the Artisan command. For each new project, include the IDE helper in that project's `composer.json` file:

   ```
   "require-dev": {
       "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.*"
   }
   ```

   Add the service provider to the providers array in the `config.php` file of your Laravel project:

   ```
   'Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider'
   ```

   Then use Artisan to generate the `_ide_helper.php` file for the project (run this command from the terminal in the root of your Laravel project directory):

   ```
   php artisan ide-helper:generate
   ```

   This is all paraphrased from the instructions on the [IDE Helper GitHub page](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper). I would recommend following those instructions to also set up your composer.json file to auto-generate a new `_ide_helper.php` whenever composer updates.

---

2. Yes. For each individual Laravel project, you'll need to update your sites mapping in the YAML file. For my projects, I use this scheme (note that you are mapping to the location relative to your Vagrant box):

   ```
   sites:
       - map: local.project.example.com
         to: /home/vagrant/Projects/project/public
   ```

   Then in your Homestead directory, run:

   ```
   vagrant provision
   ```

   You will also need to update your hosts file to point to the Vagrant box.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/hosts
   ```

   Add the line:

   ```
   127.0.0.1           local.project.example.com
   ```

   Now you should be able to access this Laravel project by hitting: `local.project.example.com:8000` in your web browser.

---

3. Assuming you followed the [Laravel installation instructions](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#install-laravel), the easiest way is to use the Laravel command in the terminal. To create a new Laravel project called "blog", navigate to `~/Developer/workspace/PHP` and run the command:

   ```
   laravel new blog
   ```

---

4. I hope the above answers get you started down the right path. The most important thing is to carefully read the Laravel documentation as it covers everything I just did but in much greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Mike Andersen, you have put me on correct way, but your solution number 1 don't work for me (using Laravel 5).

You have to run `"composer update"` after making changes to composer.json file. But, when i have doed, i got this error:

```
barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v1.2.1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock dev-master#6d705c1a0f9e2a6d73d2e9ec0e538b9dfaf4315f -> no matching package found.
```

I have got another solution:

1. remove line about "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper" from require array on composer.json file.
2. run the next line: `composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`

Then you can follow the steps proposed by Mike Andersen:

3. Add the service provider to the providers array in the config.php file of your Laravel project:

   `Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider`
4. Then use Artisan to generate the _ide_helper.php file for the project (run this command from the terminal in the root of your Laravel project directory):

   `php artisan ide-helper:generate`
5. Open your project on phpStorm and go to: `File|Synchronize`.

And you will got your laravel project updated with the last version of barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper extension

(More info: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)